# Timout for the socket connection on the router (not the client)?

Tags: router

Lets say I request a webpage (HTTP).
Then:

1. My computer opens a socket to the router
2. My computer sends request to the router (writes to socket)
3. Router does NAT translation
4. Router opens a socket to the webserver on the internet
5. Router sends request to webserver
6. Router gets response from webserver.
7. Router does reverse NAT translation
8. Router writes request to the socket connected to my computer
9. I can see the result on my computer. Yay!

So assuming I dont have any misunderstanding in the steps above, how much time can pass between steps 2 and 6? So how long will the router keep the socket open if it does NOT get a response from the webserver (but can connect)?

Comment: There's no default answer here. NAT timeouts are typically configurable on routers.

Comment: You are confused about what happens. Your  computer does not open a socket to a router if you are accessing a web page on a server. A TCP connection is between the two computers, and the routing is invisible to TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical *NAT timeout* is around:

- 1 minute for DNS
- 5 minutes for UDP
- 24 hours for TCP (If there eas a RST or FIN then it goes to 1 minute).

Most of enterprise routers have it as adjustable parameters, and internet home routers, otherwise, have it fixed and can't be modified.

Comment: Why does UDP have  a NAT timeout, there is no response packet, right?

Comment: There are responses in UDP, for example, DNS is UDP based. Your PC sends a single request and waits for a single reply.  

RTP is UDP based, for a VoIP call there will be two RTP streams and the NAT router must maintain open both ports for the streams to work.